# Looking for a data structure which provides both random and "sequential" access

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

This is a programming problem I come across very often and was wondering whether there is a data structure, either in the C++ STL or one I can implement myself which provides both random and sequential access.

An example of why I might need this:

- Say there are n types of items, (n = 1000000, for example), and there's a fixed number of each type of item (for example, 0 or 10)
- I store these items into an array, where the array index represents the type of the item, and the value represents how many items of that given type are there
- Now, I have an algorithm which iterates over all EXISTING items. To obtain these items, it is very wasteful to iterate over the entire array when all the entries are 0, except for i.e. Array[99999] and Array[999999].

Normally, I solve this by using a linked list which saves the indices of all the nonzero array entries. I implement the standard operations in this way:

**Insert(int t):**

1) If Array[t] == 0, LinkedList.push_back(t);

2) Array[t]++;

**Delete(int t):**

1) If Array[t] == 1, find and remove t from LinkedList;

2) Array[t]--;

If I want O(1) complexity for the deletion operation, I make the array store containers instead of integers. Each container contains an integer and a pointer to the respective element of the LinkedList, so I don't have to search through the list.

I would love to know whether there is a data structure which formalizes/improves this approach, or whether there's a better way to do this altogether.

Comment: I think using an unordered_map (hash map with O(1) average find), instead of a linked list will achieve the running times you desire.

Comment: Do you need the iteration to be in order? If not, how about `std::unordered_map` from type to count?

Comment: std::map has the issue of having slower run times compared to an array and unordered_map combination

Comment: There is a trade of between memory complexity and runtime complexity.

Comment: If you are in need of fast iterations through the entire set (as said in bullet-point 3) Try using a map/unordered_map containing the Objects, and then reference them all in a vector (or similiar, fast iterative dynamic array) as Object* . This allows you to quickly access members by both a key, as well as iterate quickly though all members based on index.

Comment: By "sequential", do you mean that elements are ordered from, say, smallest to largest, or that they're ordered in the same order they were inserted?

Comment: By sequential I mean I want to iterate over every single one which is nonzero, in no particular order.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, since sparse arrays are not part of the standard library and have to be "emulated".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the following requirements:

- Random access
- Fast lookups
- Fast insertions
- Fast removals
- Avoid wasted space

then you probably want something called a [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). **Sparse arrays are not part of the standard library**, so you'll have to emulate your own, using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. In a sparse array, only non-zero elements occupy space in the collection.

An `ordered_map` will have O(1) lookups, insertions, and removals, but does not provide ordered iteration. A `map` will generally have slower operations, but will provide ordered iteration. I'm oversimplifying things when I say `std::map` is slower, as it depends on the number of elements and usage patterns (a topic probably already discussed in another question).

If you must absolutely have both O(1) lookups and ordered iteration, then you can combine both a `map` and `ordered_map` and keep them in sync. At that point, you'll want to consider using [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Here's a rough sketch showing how you can implement your own sparse vector class:

```
class SparseVector
{
public:
    int get(size_t index) const
    {
        auto kv = map_.find(index);
        return (kv == map_.end()) ? 0 : kv->second;
    }

    void put(size_t index, int value)
    {
        if (value == 0)
            map_.erase(index);
        else
            map_.emplace(index, value);
    }

    // etc...

private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, int> map_;
};
```

In such a sparse vector class, you can overload `operator[]` if you wish to allow something like `sparseVec[42] = 123`.

Linear algebra libraries, such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) or [Boost.uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html), already provide templates for sparse vectors and sparse matrices.